# Split file based on text inside file

Tags: bash, loops, filter, while-loop

I'm trying to have this file split into other files. So it would take all of the lines with `"data.pdf"` in it from the input file and make a text file called `data.pdf.txt`

The data I am trying to have split is in column 5 below.

Input:

```
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ d16feafae3adf1ee0f77e6a84a476b18    0   S043GUIv02  code.bin.pe32.gui   PE32 executable for MS Windows (GUI) Intel 80386 32-bit
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ e9f6b4a413ed42987e1bfff13954faaa    0   S043GUIv02  code.bin.pe32.gui   PE32 executable for MS Windows (GUI) Intel 80386 32-bit
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ 01d0cd964020a1f498c601f9801742c1    19  S040PDFv02  data.pdf    PDF document
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ 0299a1771587043b232f760cbedbb5b7    0   S040PDFv02  data.pdf    PDF document
```

thanks I have been stuck on this and cannot do it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{ print >> $5.txt }' < input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This checks if the 5th column is `data.pdf`. If so, it prints the result in `data.pdf.txt`.

```
$ awk '$5 == "data.pdf"' your_file
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ 01d0cd964020a1f498c601f9801742c1    19  S040PDFv02  data.pdf    PDF document
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ 0299a1771587043b232f760cbedbb5b7    0   S040PDFv02  data.pdf    PDF document
```

And like this, it creates "data.pdf.txt" with this content:

```
$ awk '$5 == "data.pdf"' your_file > data.pdf.txt
```

Comment: thank you! it works perfectly How would I insert a variable in that I am making a for-loop with your line?: awk '$5 == "$filename.pdf" output.txt > $filename

Comment: @iOSecure if you want to use a variable, do like `awk -v name=$filename '$5 == name' file`

Comment: thank you, one last question! Im getting the error:awk: cmd. line:1: Unexpected token.                                                                 this is the loop:for filename in 'cat buffer.txt'; do awk -v name=$filename '$5 == name' $filename.txt

done

Comment: @iOSecure be sure the filename definition is like `filename="value"`